# check even digits on even positions in number lisp

Tags: numbers, position, lisp, common-lisp, digit

I need a function that will check if all digits in some number on even positions are even. The least significant digit is on position 1, starting from right to left. The function need to be written in lisp.
Examples:

```
245 -> true, since 4 is even
238456 -> false, since 5 is odd and 8 and 2 are even
and so on...
```

Here`s what I got:

```
(defun check(number fac)
  (cond
    ((= (/ number fac) 0) t)
    ((= (mod (/ number fac) 2 ) 0)  (check number (* 100 fac) ) )
    (nil)))
```

The initial value for `fac` is 10, we divide the number with 10, extract the second digit, check if it is even, if so proceed and divide number with 1000 to extract the 4-th digit and so on until we get over all digits, than the function returns true, meanwhile if some digit is odd the function should return `nil`.
But something is wrong and the function return `nil` all the time , when I call it like `(check 22 10)` for example.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a non recursive solution that checks for the correctness of the parameter:

```
(defun check(num)
  (assert (integerp num))
  (loop for i = (truncate num 10) then (truncate i 100) until (zerop i) 
     always (evenp i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variant. Basicly I'm converting number to list (through string though, maybe not the best way), then reverse it, select every second element and check it all for being even.

```
;; Helper for getting every 
(defun get-all-nth (list period)
  "Get all NTH element in the list"
  (remove-if-not
    (let ((iterator 0))
      (lambda (x)
        (declare (ignore x))
        (= 0 (mod (incf iterator) period)))) list))

(defun check-evens (num)
  "Checks if all digits in some number on even positions are even.
   Goes Rigth-to-left."
  (assert (integerp num))
  (every #'evenp
         (get-all-nth
           (reverse
             (map 'list #'digit-char-p
                  (prin1-to-string num))) 2)))
```

Some test cases:

```
CL-USER> (check-evens 123)
T
CL-USER> (check-evens 238456)
NIL 
CL-USER> (check-evens 238446)
T
CL-USER> (check-evens 23844681)
T
```